# Make a rectangle transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF, I have rectangle like this:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Name="rectangleSignal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" >
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="image0" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

In .cs file. In some cases, I want to set this rectangle to be transparent.
I have code like this,
What should I do for Resourcekey, that I can make this rectangele be transparent?
thank you

```
rectangleSignal.SetResourceReference(Rectangle.FillProperty, "image0");
```

Edited:

I figured out myself.
Just setting peroperty to "#FFFFFFFF"
It will be fine.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: `#FFFFFFFF` is solid white? Anyway, you should either accept my answer or post yours and accept that, but answers certainly *do not* belong into the question and answered questions should have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep that reference you can add `Brushes.Transparent` as a resource with that key, if you do not need to do that make an assigment to Fill. Alternatively you can also just set the `Visibility` or `Opacity`.